# Equation over Z

Tags: diophantine-equations

Solve the equation $xy+1=3x+y$ over $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Indeed,
$$ xy+1=3x+y  \Longleftrightarrow  (x-1)(y-3)=2 $$

or $ \textrm{Div}(2)=\{k \in \mathbb{Z}/ k|2 \}=\{-1;1;-2;2\}$ Then

$(x-1)/2 \implies x-1 \in  \textrm{Div}(2) \implies x\in \{0,2,-1,3  \} $
$(y-3)/2 \implies y-3 \in  \textrm{Div}(2) \implies y\in \{2,4,1,5  \} $
$$S=\{(0,2),(2,4),(-1,1),(2,5)\}$$ AM i right ??

Answer (score 3):

$(0,2)$ is not a solution because $(0-1)(2-3)\neq 2$

What you have observed $xy+1=3x+y  \Longleftrightarrow  (x-1)(y-3)=2$ is appreciable..

For it to hold in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ only possibilities are..

- $(x-1)=2$ and $(y-3)=1$.. What does this say about $x,y$?
- $(x-1)=-2$ and $(y-3)=-1$.. What does this say about $x,y$?
- $(x-1)=1$ and $(y-3)=2$.. What does this say about $x,y$?
- $(x-1)=-1$ and $(y-3)=-2$.. What does this say about $x,y$?

Comment: what about others solutions am i right

Comment: @Educ :
 
see the edit...

Comment: how could you choice exactly this possibilities  and if we took 1st possibilty gives $x= 2$ and $y = 5 \implies 2.5 \neq 2$

Comment: @Educ:  like you said... my $(x-1)$ has to be a factor of $2$ and at the same time $y-3$ has to be a factor of $2$ and at the same time their product has to be $2$.... I can not take $x-1=2$ and $y-3=2$ as this would give me $(x-1)(y-3)=4$ which is not what i wanted..

Comment: as you said the all solutions are : $\{ (3,4);(-1,2);(2,5),(0,1)\}$

Comment: @Educ : yes.. those are all solutions.. Very well done :)

Answer (score 0):

$(x-1)(y-3)=2\implies(x-1,y-3)\in\{(1, 2), ((2,1),(-1,-2),(-2,-1)\}.$

Comment: why negative vote??

Comment: Perhaps someone would prefer to see two times $y-3$ instead of $y-1$ and $y-2$.

Comment: @barto: I would have preferred a comment or an edit rather then a silent downvote...